# How do I create a 3D selection tool in C++ with OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

Basicly all I want to do is click somewhere in my opengl window where there is a model, then make some sort of check to see if I have selected an object or not. I have no idea how I would do this I understand the opengl but not the math, some source code would be good.

Answer (score 1):

The basic "to do" is rather simple: Cast a ray from your view into your 3D world and intersect it with your objects.

A very simple approach would be this:

- Determine the viewport position that has been clicked.
- Inverse the view/projection matrix or use some other way to determine a line from your camera going through the point clicked. You can skip the matrix stuff if you know the field of view of your camera. Use the camera's "forward vector" and transpose it accordingly (e.g. clicked on the far left of the viewport -> rotate the vector by half the horizontal field of view).
- Intersect that line with the bounding boxes of your objects to determine the item that has been clicked (use to closest one to determine the foremost object).

One rather elaborate example implementation can be found [here](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/selection.htm) (this is using GL_SELECTION; another approach).

Another solution can be found [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12360/how-do-you-determine-which-object-surface-the-users-pointing-at-with-lwjgl) (using the math way).

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to render each select-able geometry in a *selection buffer* with a different ID and then get the ID that is under the mouse.